# Netty 4 Calls being blocked , Simple Telnet Server

Tags: java, sockets, connection, netty

I am trying to play around with netty api using Netty Telnet server to check if the true asynchronous behaviour could be observed or not.

Below are the three classes being used

TelnetServer.java

```
public class TelnetServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(1);
          EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
          try {
              ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
              b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
               .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
               .handler(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO))
               .childHandler(new TelnetServerInitializer());


              b.bind(8989).sync().channel().closeFuture().sync();
          } finally {
              bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
              workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
          }
    }

}
```

TelnetServerInitializer.java

```
public class TelnetServerInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> {

    private static final StringDecoder DECODER = new StringDecoder();
    private static final StringEncoder ENCODER = new StringEncoder();

    private static final TelnetServerHandler SERVER_HANDLER = new TelnetServerHandler();


    final EventExecutorGroup executorGroup = new DefaultEventExecutorGroup(2);

    public TelnetServerInitializer() {

    }

    @Override
    public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
        ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();


        // Add the text line codec combination first,
        pipeline.addLast(new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(8192, Delimiters.lineDelimiter()));
        // the encoder and decoder are static as these are sharable
        pipeline.addLast(DECODER);
        pipeline.addLast(ENCODER);

        // and then business logic.
        pipeline.addLast(executorGroup,"handler",SERVER_HANDLER);
    }
}
```

TelnetServerHandler.java

```
/**
 * Handles a server-side channel.
 */
@Sharable
public class TelnetServerHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<String> {

    @Override
    public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        // Send greeting for a new connection.
        ctx.write("Welcome to " + InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName() + "!\r\n");
        ctx.write("It is " + new Date() + " now.\r\n");
        ctx.flush();
        ctx.channel().config().setAutoRead(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, String request) throws Exception {
        // Generate and write a response.

        System.out.println("request = "+ request);

        String response;
        boolean close = false;
        if (request.isEmpty()) {
            response = "Please type something.\r\n";
        } else if ("bye".equals(request.toLowerCase())) {
            response = "Have a good day!\r\n";
            close = true;
        } else {
            response = "Did you say '" + request + "'?\r\n";
        }

        // We do not need to write a ChannelBuffer here.
        // We know the encoder inserted at TelnetPipelineFactory will do the conversion.
        ChannelFuture future = ctx.write(response);

        Thread.sleep(10000);
        // Close the connection after sending 'Have a good day!'
        // if the client has sent 'bye'.
        if (close) {
            future.addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
        ctx.flush();
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
        cause.printStackTrace();
        ctx.close();
    }
}
```

Now when i connect through telnet client and send commands hello hello hello three times

the request doesn't reach channelRead until first response to channelRead is being done is there any way i can make it asynchronous completely as to receive three hello as soon as they are available on socket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Netty uses 1 thread max for every incoming read per handler, meaning that the next call to `channelRead` will only be dispatched after the previous call has been completed. This is required to for correct working of most handlers, including the sending back of messages in the proper order. If the amount of computation is really complex, another solution is using a custom thread pool for the messages.

If the other operation is instead a other kind of connection, you should use that as a async connection too. You can only get asynchronous if every part does this correctly.